# Как скачивать файл в папку Images?

Tags: python

Задача в том, что юзер отсылает ссылку на фото, она открывается в яндекс, а после скачивается в определённую папку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import webbrowser
import requests
import pathlib
import urllib
import os



Name = input("Привет друг, как тебя зовут? ", )
Age = input(f"Приятно познакомиться {Name}, сколько тебе лет? ")
Username = input(f"Хорошо, раз тебе {Age}, можешь написать мне свой никнейм? ")
Photo = input(f"{Username}? Клёвый никнейм, но мой круче). Ладно, скинь мне любую фокту(либо ссылка, либо путь)")


def profile():
    f = open("profile.txt", "w")
    f.write(f"Имя-{Name}\nВозраст-{Age}\nНикнейм-{Username}\nВаша фотка-{Photo}")
    f.close()
    
profile()
    
    
img_data = requests.get(Photo).content
with open('image_name.jpg', 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(img_data)


def open():
    webbrowser.open(f"{Photo}", new=0)
    
open()
```

Comment: Непонятно в чём вопрос. Ну сохраняйте фотку в файл `images\image_name.jpg`, или имеется в виду папка "Картинки" в Винде? Или что?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проблему решил, спасибо за помощь!